# How to clear all my storage and get my GB back

Tags: storage, cleanup

So I want to know how to clear all my storage on my computer and have all 16GB of free space. The storage SSD I'm using is a 16GB Kingston SSD that is installed in my Chromebook.

The reason I'm doing this because I'll give this old computer to my mom :)

But idk how to clear the storage and start fresh with all 16GB available.[image]

Comment: Reinstall it using a USB stick I would say

Comment: I lost my only USB months ago at the airport sadly... I only have a 2TB SSD from western digital, but will that work?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in the internal storage of your 16 GB Chromebook? Ubuntu is supposed to take almost 16 GB space, and there is no way to clear that space without removing Ubuntu. In that case, are you trying tor remove Ubuntu and restore ChromeOS?

Comment: In case this is Acer C720 Chromebook (since its model number is Peppy), you can upgrade the NGFF M.2 SSD https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/acer-c720-chromebook/#firmware

Answer (score 2):

### Clear all Storage and get GB back

- Create a new user named Mom with Administrator privileges.
- Delete your existing User and their home.
- Reboot
- Run the command `sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean` to delete APT cache.
- Run the command `sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=20M` to remove all but the recent system logs.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi: Thank you for the edit.